# Sobreponer botones en Tabla

Tags: html, css, vue.js

estoy haciendo un proyecto en VueJs3 y necesito poner estos 4 botones sobre la tabla sobreponerlos o sobrescribirlo, he intentado de varias maneras pero no me da el CSS ¿Tal vez tienes la solución o haz hecho algo similar? Te agradezco de antemano a continuación imágenes para ser mas detallado y el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer hover, aparecen los 4 botones que necesito ubicar. Como puedes observar en la imagen ahi intento ser lo mas explicito posible ¿Qué propiedad puedo utilizar o que código, ya que es muy necesario hacer el proyecto así pq el compañero del Figma lo hizo asi, gracias.

```
<template>
  <div class="tabla ma-8">
    <table v-if="headers.length" class="claims-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
             <!-- Checkbox Column, en lugar de ngfor* se usa v-for -->
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </th>
          <template v-for="column in headers" :key="column.code"> 
            <th>{{ column.name }}</th>
          </template>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <!-- mouseover-mouseleave esta propiedades exclusivas de Vue nos permiten hacer el hoover de los botones-->
        <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index"
            :id="'row-'+item.id"
            @mouseover="hoveredRow = index"
            @mouseleave="hoveredRow = null">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="selection" :value="item.id"/>
          </td>
          <template v-for="column in headers" :key="column.code">
            <td>
              {{ item[column.code] }}
            </td>
          </template>
          <td v-if="index === hoveredRow"  class="buttons">
            <div>
              <button @click="onClickButtonEdit(item)" ><img src="svg/Edit.svg" alt="Editar" height="auto" width="32px" class="mr-2"> </button>
              <button @click="onClickButtonImport(item)"><img src="svg/Import.svg" alt="Importar" height="auto" width="32px" class="mr-2"> </button>
              <button @click="onClickButtonDelete(item)"><img src="svg/Delete.svg" alt="Eliminar" height="auto" width="32px" class="mr-2"> </button>
              <button @click="onClickButtonCampaign(item)"><img src="svg/Campaign.svg" alt="Campaña" height="auto" width="32px" class="mr-2">  </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import sampleTable from '../../sample-table';
import sampleData from '../../sample-data';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      headers: sampleTable,
      items: sampleData,
      hoveredRow: null //No se esta pasando el Mouse, por lo tanto no muestra nada
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onClickButtonEdit(item) {
      // Lógica para el botón de editar
    },
    onClickButtonImport(item) {
      // Lógica para el botón de importar
    },
    onClickButtonDelete(item) {
      // Lógica para el botón de borrar
    },
    onClickButtonCampaign(item) {
      // Lógica para el botón de Campana
    }
  }
}
</script>


<style>
.tabla {
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

th,
td {
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  background-color: var(--primary-soft-color);
}

td, th {
  padding: 25px;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

td input[type=checkbox] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

td button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    
  }

</style>
```

Comment: o sea, en la última columna: "no documento", busca que al hacer `hover` en cualquiera de sus filas aparezcan estos 4 botones? como por decir de algún modo: "Un mini dialogo", "tooltip" sobre esa misma fila <td> ?

Comment: Asi es, he intentado mucho y no me da ninguna opcion siempre me quedan por fuera y me ocupan espacio como si los botones fueran otro row.

Comment: ok, creo la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Aplicando un poco de css se crea un tooltip donde con estilo dinámico para su visibilidad se genera superposición en el td según el indice donde se ejecute el hover.

Simulo la tabla, según su código solo adapte a su lógica.

Uso de:

- `@mouseleave` Seguimiento cuando sale el cursor del td
- `@mouseenter` Detecta la entrada del cursor al td (*según el td donde se aplica el hover*)
- `Style Bindings` Estilos dinamicos. (*Visibilidad del tooltip*)

**HTML:**

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th  v-for="(title, i) in header" :key="i">{{ title }}</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="({nombre, edad, acciones}, i) in data" :key="i">
        <td>{{ nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ edad }}</td>
        <td @mouseenter="showTooltip(i)" @mouseleave="hideTooltip(i)">
          {{acciones }}
          <div :class="{'tooltip': true, 'visible': activeTooltip === i}">
            <button @click="onClickButtonEdit">E</button> <!--Agrega sus imagenes o iconos. -->
            <button @click="onClickButtonImport">B</button>
            <button @click="onClickButtonDelete">D</button>
            <button @click="onClickButtonCampaign">R</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //Simulo la tabla. Solo adapte según su código.
      header:["Nombre", "Edad", "Acciones"],
      data: [
        { nombre: "Juan", edad: 25, acciones: "Ver más" },
        { nombre: "Pedro", edad: 32, acciones: "Ver más" },
        { nombre: "María", edad: 27, acciones: "Ver más" },
      ],
      activeTooltip: null, //Estado tooltip
    };
  },
  methods: {
    //tooltip
    showTooltip(i) {  this.activeTooltip = i; }, //Motrar
    hideTooltip() { this.activeTooltip = null; }, //Ocultar

      //Eventos de botón
    onClickButtonEdit() {console.log("click edit") },
    onClickButtonImport() {console.log("click import") },
    onClickButtonDelete() { console.log("click delete")  },
    onClickButtonCampaign() { console.log("clickcampaign") }
  },
};
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
/** Puede modificar la animación a su gusto, usar sass etc..  */
.tooltip { /*Clase usada para generar el tooltup*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.tooltip.visible { /*Visibilidad del tooltip*/
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip button {
  margin: 0 1px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; /*agregamos esta propiedad para que el tooltip esté posicionado relativo al td*/
}
</style>
```

El ejemplo es práctico. Puede copiar y pegar para verlo enseguida.